# Robot Framework:: How to Exclude Test Suites

Tags: robotframework

We have our Test Suites growing like anything. We are able to run TC's with include and exclude TAGS in Argument files.
But I wonder is there a way to  exclude Test Suites so we can save some execution time.  all the command line options work with TC only.

Comment: How you checked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026891/how-to-exclude-test-suites-in-robot-framework-we-are-using-maven

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in RIDE, or are you asking the more general question of how to exclude suites no matter what tool you're using? Have you read the user guide, it has lots of information about including and excluding tests.

Answer (score 2):

In RIDE select each of the suites folders and on the Settings editor add at `Force Tags` unique tags. This is the same as to create in each Suite folder, a file named `__init__.robot` with the following example content:

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags        excluded
```

You can also choose to use `Default Tags` in each Test Suite file. This tag will be set for the tests without any specific tag.

Run the tests by checking the "Skip tests with these tags" checkbox and filling with the desired tags. You could also enter `--exclude excluded` in the Arguments field of the test runner.

Another option is to "View All Tags (F7)" and use the search functions to Include or Exclude by tag. In the below example, I have used "Excluded Tag Search" and then "Add all to selected". I had ran the tests previously, with the excluded tag in the Arguments.

[image: capture of RIDE tag selection tools]

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are using Pycharm editor. However will use force tag as you said and see